# Controller setting a local variable instead of calling setter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application, I have a method called `pagetitle=` which sets the page title and the helper method `pagetitle` which creates the page title based on the string provided (or absent).

The `pagetitle=` is defined on the `ApplicationController` super class and the `pagetitle` is defined in the `ApplicationHelper` class.

My problem is that whenever I call `pagetitle = "Some string"` the method is not called, rails prefers to create the local variable `pagetitle` instead of calling the method.

If I call `self.pagetitle = "Some string"` then the method is called.

Is this the intended behavior? What am I missing here?

TL;DR: Why `pagetitle=` creates a local variable and `self.pagetitle=` calls my method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the intended behavior.

You use `self.` to write the instance variable, otherwise Ruby just creates local variable.

Comment: Out of interest, how does `pagetitle=("some string")` behave?

Comment: @Yule it is the same as `pagetitle="some string"`, if that's what you're asking about

Comment: yep, that's all. Thanks.

Comment: @Yule no probs :)